# I am trying to write a program where i have an Emp class and make all the members of Emp class available to another class

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program where I have an `Emp` class, and I make all the members of the `Emp` class available to another class.

But I am getting an attribute error.

Code:

```
#create class and make all member of call available for another class

class Employee():
    #this is method

    def Display(self,a,id,sal):
        print("Name of the Employee",a)
        print("Id of the employee",id)
        print("salary of the employee",sal)


class Myclass():

    def MyMethod(emp_object):
        emp_object.sal=emp_object.sal+1000
        emp_object.Display("abc",121,5000)


emp_object= Employee()
emp_object.Display("abc",121,5000)
Myclass.MyMethod(emp_object)
```

**Error**:

> AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'sal'

Comment: There is a very basic mistake here... Just as the error said, `sal` isn't an object under employee. It wasn't even stored...

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better for you to read on this, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html, to further your knowledge about classes. On your question, modifying the `Display` method will solve the problem.

```py
class Employee():
    #this is method
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ''
        self.id = 0
        self.sal = 0

    def Display(self,a,id,sal):
        #If you want to override the values, just reassign them
        self.a = a 
        self.id = id
        self.sal = sal
        print("Name of the Employee",a)
        print("Id of the employee",id)
        print("salary of the employee",sal)
```